# How to implement a time limited execution mechanism in CLISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

What I have in mind is something like:

```
(run (long-calculation vars) time-limit)
```

which returns the result of `(long-calculation vars)` or `nil` if `time-limit` is reached.

Comment: This is implementation-dependent. What Lisp implementation do you use?

Answer (score 1):

If you could find an implementation for the `amb` operator, then you could do something like this:

```
(defmacro run (comp time-limit)
  `(amb comp
       (progn (delay ,time-limit)
              nil)))
```

Be careful not to mistake this with the McCarthy `amb` operator. `amb` should evaluate both its arguments in separate threads and pick whichever finishes first. For example, in Haskell, it's described in [Data.Unamb](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unamb/0.2.4/doc/html/Data-Unamb.html#v%3aamb).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for an implementation of amb actually:) Or a pointer to an existing library.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using bordeaux-threads, spawning a thread for the computation, and if it doesn't return by the timer, reaping the thread and returning nil.

Answer (score 1):

Found this lisp code out in the wild that seems to do what you want:

http://www.eurogaran.com/downloads/lisp/limitools/limitime.lsp

I launched 'Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.7-r14925M  (DarwinX8664)', pasted the lisp code in that site into the listener (it all compiled), and ran this:

```
? (with-max-time 1 (print 5))

5 
5
? (with-max-time 1 (sleep 2) (print 5))
? (quit)
```

Hopefully this will help you from having to roll out your own.